# How to find from right using a regex in Rust?

Tags: regex, rust

Right now I've reversed both the string and the regex to mimic rfind with a regex. Below is a sample program:

```
#[static_init::dynamic]
// static r: Regex = regex::Regex::new(r"a\d").unwrap();
static r: Regex = regex::Regex::new(r"\da").unwrap();
let mut s = "123a123a456";
let sr = s.chars().rev().collect::<String>();
let option = r.find(&sr).unwrap();

let start = s.chars().count() - option.end();
let end = s.chars().count() - option.start();

println!("start: {:#?}", start);
println!("end: {:#?}", end);
```

As you can see, I have to reverse the regex from `a\d` to `\da` as well as the string `s` to mimic an `rfind` operation. Is there an easier way? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, regex was always designed to be a forward-searching language and is very hard to reverse in the general case, so I don't think there's an easier way.

Comment: The [`regex_automata`](https://docs.rs/regex-automata/0.1.10/regex_automata/index.html) looks like it may have the tools to do it. See potentially helpful [`reverse()`](https://docs.rs/regex-automata/0.1.10/regex_automata/index.html?search=reverse) and [`rfind()`](https://docs.rs/regex-automata/0.1.10/regex_automata/index.html?search=rfind) functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

regex-automata kinda supports this without having to do the reversals yourself. I say "kinda" because you have to stitch things together yourself:

```
use regex_automata::{dense, DFA};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let dfarev = dense::Builder::new()
        .reverse(true)
        .build_with_size::<u32>(r"a\d")?;
    let dfafwd = dense::Builder::new()
        .anchored(true)
        .longest_match(true)
        .build_with_size::<u32>(r"a\d")?;

    let haystack = "123a123a456";
    let mut at = haystack.len();
    // This simple loop is wrong if the regex can match the empty string.
    while let Some(start) = dfarev.rfind_at(haystack.as_bytes(), at) {
        let end = dfafwd.find(haystack[start..].as_bytes())
            .map(|i| start + i)
            .expect("reverse match implies a forward match");
        println!("match:{:?}:{:?}", (start, end), &haystack[start..end]);
        at = start;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

And the program's output is:

```
match:(7, 9):"a4"
match:(3, 5):"a1"
```

Note that for `regex-automata 0.1`, it is important to read [the section on differences between it and the regex crate](https://docs.rs/regex-automata/0.1.10/regex_automata/#differences-with-the-regex-crate). The main difference is that `regex-automata 0.1` only provides fully compiled DFAs. (The next version of regex-automata won't be limited to fully compiled DFAs.)